# How to use wildcard search by json column type in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I got three data in MySQL

```
[{"key": "field_1", "value": "test_1"}, {"key": "field_2", "value": "test_2"}]
```

```
[{"key": "field_1", "value": "1"}, {"key": "field_2", "value": "test_2"}]
```

```
[{"key": "field_2", "value": "test_2"}, {"key": "field_1", "value": "test_1"}]
```

I need to search data which include `"key" = "field_1"` and `"value" like "%est%"`, all I know is only `json_search` have wildcard function, so I've tried:

```sql
select *
from `table`
where json_contains(metadata, '[{"key": "field_1"}]') and json_search(metadata, 'one', '%est%', null, '$[*].value') is not null
```

Three of the data were found, I know the problem is that I need to use `json_search` on the data which includes "key": "filed_1", or it will search all data and find the result which is matched, is there any function to make it?

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: In this case, only 1 and 3 matched

Comment: No, all rows matches. See https://dbfiddle.uk/9GeEVtdu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    metadata
FROM
    t
WHERE
    JSON_CONTAINS(metadata, '[{"key": "field_1"}]')
AND
    JSON_SEARCH(
        metadata,
        'one',
        '%est%',
        null,
        JSON_UNQUOTE(REPLACE(JSON_SEARCH(metadata, 'one', 'field_1', null, '$[*].key'), 'key', 'value'))
    ) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE test (metadata JSON)
SELECT '[{"key": "field_1", "value": "test_1"}, {"key": "field_2", "value": "test_2"}]' metadata
  UNION ALL
SELECT '[{"key": "field_1", "value": "1"}, {"key": "field_2", "value": "test_2"}]'
  UNION ALL
SELECT '[{"key": "field_2", "value": "test_2"}, {"key": "field_1", "value": "test_1"}]';
SELECT CAST(metadata AS CHAR) FROM test;
```

| CAST(metadata AS CHAR) |
| --- |
| [{"key": "field_1", "value": "test_1"}, {"key": "field_2", "value": "test_2"}] |
| [{"key": "field_1", "value": "1"}, {"key": "field_2", "value": "test_2"}] |
| [{"key": "field_2", "value": "test_2"}, {"key": "field_1", "value": "test_1"}] |

```
SELECT CAST(metadata AS CHAR)
FROM test
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(test.metadata,
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (`key` TEXT PATH '$.key',
                                      `value` TEXT PATH '$.value')) jsontable
WHERE jsontable.key = 'field_1'
  AND jsontable.value LIKE '%est%';
```

| CAST(metadata AS CHAR) |
| --- |
| [{"key": "field_1", "value": "test_1"}, {"key": "field_2", "value": "test_2"}] |
| [{"key": "field_2", "value": "test_2"}, {"key": "field_1", "value": "test_1"}] |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/paepls14)